# How to push email attachments to google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to automate our workflow when our clients send data via an email to auto ingest it into a cloud storage bucket.  Anyone know of a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Process your received emails and extract the attachments and store in Google Cloud Storage? Storing data in Cloud Storage is well documented. Extracting attachments depends on how you plan to process email and on your email system design. Edit your question with details. Note: Stack Overflow does not design solutions for you. We will try to help you with software development questions. Read these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.